# How to show different screens fo Google Maps?

Tags: flutter, maps, bloc

I am not sure how to format title, but problem is simple to explain. I want e.g. two buttons, one button opens Gmap and shows current location, second button opens default state of map (without current location). Problem is that I don't want to make two classes and that buttons are not on same screen. I need to somehow pass the argument which gives origin of map call.

edit: Second map should also show some markers which are not visible when current location is shown

Comment: How are you getting current location for the device?

Comment: In google maps widget I have argument myLocationEnabled = true;

Comment: So, if I get your right, you only want to hide/show `myLocationEnabled` from 2 different screen respectively?

Comment: Yes, but I want to show also different markers when I come to different screen. I should add it in description..

Comment: Are you able to get the current latitude or longitude before opening the Google maps?

Comment: I haven't tried, whats your idea?

Comment: You will have to use `geolocator` library to get user's current location, once you have it, I can further give you the idea.

Comment: I need a help with routing and passing parameters, problem is not connected to strictly maps

Comment: I solved it using fluro package ! thanks